# WebGL2 getUniformLocation returns null on Android

Tags: android, typescript, glsl, webgl

I'm pretty stumped on this one. I have a fragment shader with a handful of uniforms. I'm fetching the location of the uniforms like this:

```js
    this.gl.useProgram(this.program)
    
    // Get uniform locations
    for (const uniform of [
      'u_resolution',
      'u_data_resolution',
      'u_pix_to_map',
      'u_gps_to_data',
      'u_data',
      'u_colormap',
      'u_product_min',
      'u_product_max',
      'u_product_cutoff',
      'u_alpha',
      'u_no_data',
    ]) {
      const loc = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, uniform)

      if (loc === null) {
        throw Error(`could not get location for uniform ${uniform}`)
      }

      this.uniformLocations[uniform] = loc
    }
```

My fragment shader is the following:

```c
#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

const float E = 2.71828182845904523536028747135266250;
const float PI = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288;
const float RADIUS = 6378137.0;
const float HALF_SIZE = PI * RADIUS;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_data_resolution;
uniform mat3 u_pix_to_map;
uniform mat3 u_gps_to_data;
uniform sampler2D u_data;
uniform sampler2D u_colormap;
uniform float u_product_min;
uniform float u_product_max;
uniform float u_product_cutoff;
uniform float u_alpha;
uniform float u_no_data;

out vec4 fragColor;

vec2 apply(mat3 transform, vec2 coordinate) {
    float x = (transform[0][0] * coordinate.x) + (transform[0][1] * coordinate.y) + transform[0][2];
    float y = (transform[1][0] * coordinate.x) + (transform[1][1] * coordinate.y) + transform[1][2];

    return vec2(x, y);
}

vec2 mapToGPS(vec2 coordinate) {
    return vec2(
        (180.0 * coordinate.x) / HALF_SIZE,
        (360.0 * atan(exp(coordinate.y / RADIUS))) / PI - 90.0
    );
}

vec2 screenSpaceToCanvasSpace(vec2 coordinate, vec2 resolution) {
    return vec2(
        coordinate.x,
        -1.0 * (coordinate.y - resolution.y)
    );
}

float getDataValue(vec2 coords) {
    return texture(u_data, vec2(coords.x / u_data_resolution.x, coords.y / u_data_resolution.y)).x;
}

float bilerp(float x, float y, float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2, float z11, float z12, float z21, float z22) {
    // Sometimes the floor and ceiling values are too close to each other; if this is the case, just return the average.
    if (abs(x2 - x1) < 0.00001 || abs(y2 - y1) < 0.00001) { 
        return (z11 + z12 + z21 + z22) / 4.0;
    }

    float zxy1 = (( (x2 - x) / (x2 - x1) ) * z11) + (( (x - x1) / (x2 - x1) ) * z21);
    float zxy2 = (( (x2 - x) / (x2 - x1) ) * z12) + (( (x - x1) / (x2 - x1) ) * z22);

    return (( (y2 - y) / (y2 - y1) ) * zxy1) + (( (y - y1) / (y2 - y1) ) * zxy2);
}

float normalizeValue(float value) {
    return (value - u_product_min) / (u_product_max - u_product_min); 
}

vec3 getColor(float normalizedValue) {
    return texture(u_colormap, vec2(normalizedValue, 0.5)).rgb;
}

void main() {
    vec2 adjustedCoords = screenSpaceToCanvasSpace(gl_FragCoord.xy, u_resolution);

    vec2 mapCoords = apply(u_pix_to_map, adjustedCoords);

    vec2 gpsCoords = mapToGPS(mapCoords);

    vec2 dataCoords = apply(u_gps_to_data, gpsCoords);

    if (dataCoords.x < 0.0 || dataCoords.x > u_data_resolution.x || dataCoords.y < 0.0 || dataCoords.y > u_data_resolution.y) {
        fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        return;
    }

    float x1 = floor(dataCoords.x);
    float x2 = ceil(dataCoords.x);
    float y1 = floor(dataCoords.y);
    float y2 = ceil(dataCoords.y);    

    float z11 = getDataValue(vec2(x1, y1));
    float z12 = getDataValue(vec2(x1, y2));
    float z21 = getDataValue(vec2(x2, y1));
    float z22 = getDataValue(vec2(x2, y2));

    if (abs(z11 - u_no_data) < 0.01) {
        fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        return;
    }

    if (abs(z12 - u_no_data) < 0.01) {
        fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        return;
    }

    if (abs(z21 - u_no_data) < 0.01) {
        fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        return;
    }

    if (abs(z22 - u_no_data) < 0.01) {
        fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        return;
    }


    float value = bilerp(dataCoords.x, dataCoords.y, x1, x2, y1, y2, z11, z12, z21, z22);

    float normalizedValue = normalizeValue(value);

    vec3 color = getColor(normalizedValue);

    float normalizedCutoff = normalizeValue(u_product_cutoff);

    float alpha = u_alpha;

    if (normalizedValue < normalizedCutoff) {
        alpha -= (u_alpha * ((normalizedCutoff - normalizedValue) / normalizedCutoff));
    }

    fragColor = vec4(color, alpha);
}
```

On all other devices and browsers (Windows, Linux, Mac, iOS, Firefox, Safari, Chrome) this code functions and the uniform locations are fetched correctly.

Only on Android (both Firefox and Chrome), `u_resolution` and `u_pix_to_map` return null. Also of note, I cannot reproduce this in an Android emulator running API 34. I have only seen this on physical devices running Android 11 or Android 12.

The uniforms are definitely used so they should not be optimized out of the shader.

If a set a breakpoint after the shader is compiled and run:

```js
this.gl.getActiveUniform(this.program, 0)
```

the result is:

```
WebGLActiveInfo {size: 1, type: 35664, name: 'u_resolution'}
```

This tells me that this uniform is present in the compiled shader. However, if I attempt to get that uniform immediately after:

```js
this.gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_resolution')
```

the result is `null`.

Also of note, there does not appear to be an error:

```js
this.gl.getError()
0
```

I'm not sure how to debug this further, but the only possibilities I can think of are:

- The uniforms are incorrectly removed from the compiled shader by the GLSL compiler on Android
- I've done something to break the uniform "packing" on Android
- There is some other bug in Chrome and/or Firefox on Android

Any idea what the issue is, or even just some further steps I can take to debug this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a "webgl2" context on your Android device?

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes, I have confirmed that. I'm able to get the context and compile the shader. This appears to impact essentially every Android device I've tried, except for an emulator running API 34. Multiple friends devices, other emulators, and my test device all exhibit this issue.

I suspect this may be a bug in the WebGL compiler/linker on Android.

Comment: The size of the uniforms is limited per shader and depends on the hardware. You may exceed this limit on an Android device.

Comment: @Rabbid76 according to https://webglreport.com/?v=2, on the test Android device I have all of the maximums for the fragment shader are greater than or equal to those reported on working devices.